# Ctrl keys not working on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my workstation last week. The ctrl keys did not work initially until I google'd the reason and found a link that stated to download gnome-tweak-tools, and then modify some setting. This made it so that the ctrl keys worked. But for the past few days, the ctrl keys have stopped working again.

I can't even do ctrl+c in terminal. When I type this, it just types the letter c.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

my left ctrl key not work but right ctrl key is ok.

when I enter settings->device->keyborad ,then **reset all shortcut-key**. the left ctrl key is ok.

Comment: Worked for me, too... Strange. Although in my case CTRL did work in some cases (e.g. CTRL+C) but not others (e.g. CTRL+Shift+T)

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks! I can now Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V to my heart's content.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in *Language settings → Manage installed languages → Keyboard input method system: None*. If IBus is set, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>V</kbd>  and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> do not work